# Exibir todos os registros de uma coluna

Tags: php, mysql

fiz uma `query` onde obtive resultado desta consulta, no entando o que preciso é este resultado exibe apenas uma linha, um único registro mas na realidade te mais de um: segue o código abaixo e por favor me mostrem onde estou errando pois não consigo ver o erro ou a falta de algum elemento..

```
if (empty($_POST['contrato'])) {"";} 
     if(isset($_POST['contrato'])) {"";
        if($_POST['contrato'] == "") {"";}
        else{   

            $cmd = "SELECT login FROM tecnicos GROUP BY Area = '%$Roteamento%' ";
            $login_tecnico = mysqli_query($conn, $cmd);

            $row = mysqli_num_rows($login_tecnico);

            if($row == " ") {" ";} else{

            while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($login_tecnico)) {
            $tec_login = $res['login'];
```

exibe com sucesso a variavel `tec_loogin`, mas como disse este exibe apenas 1 registro quando na verdade tem mais de um, minha pergunta é como exibir todos?? help me...

Comment: Você está agrupando todos resultados com Area = Roteamento, se todos seus registros forem assim, certamente retornará um unico resultado, tente usar o WHERE

Comment: ja fiz assim, sem êxito.

Comment: apenas quero fazer uma consulta e por meio dela exibir todos os resultados da coluna entende.

Comment: você pode mostrar alguns valores que estão na coluna `Area`?

Comment: sim posso, são estas areas: AREA 05
AREA 06
AREA 24
AREA 25
AREA 30
AREA 31
AREA20
e cada area tem seu respectivo login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso ta acontecendo pois a cada repetição do while, o seu código rerescreve o que está em `$tec_login`, por isso que só mostrará um registro. Você pode concatenar tudo nessa mesma variável ou guardar cada login em um elemento de um array:

Concatenando:

```
$tec_login = '';
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($login_tecnico)) {
            $tec_login .= $res['login'].' ';
}
```

Array:

```
$tec_login = [];
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($login_tecnico)) {
            $tec_login[] = $res['login'];
}
```

Do jeito que seu código está fazendo o `while`, seria a mesma coisa de, por exemplo:

```
$tec_login = 'valor 1';
$tec_login = 'valor 2';
$tec_login = 'valor 3';
```

Onde, no fim das contas, o valor da variável seria apenas `'valor3'`.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84383/discussion-on-answer-by-tropicoder12-exibir-todos-os-registros-de-uma-coluna)